# assigning null to XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

We have JAXB generated method setCHECKDT(XMLGregorianCalendar value).
From the actual business logic(we can not modify the business logic) we may get CHECKDT as null value some times, the same needs to be assigned to the method for generating the xml.

While setting null date to the setter,  is vanishing from the xml. Please suggest a way to assign null value to the XMLGregorianCalendar date or any way to generate  tag.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the Java property to null will correctly cause the element to be left out from the XML when serialized. If you still want the element in the XML, your options are either:

1. Write your own date/time converter that can handle empty tags on (de)serializing (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp155652).
2. Annotate the Java property with nillable as follows:

   ```
   @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
   private XMLGregorianCalendar yourProperty;
   ```

Now the serialized XML will contain the element, even if it is null. The element will be marked with an attribute 'nil="true"':

```
<yourProperty xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```